# How to set Recovery Mode on MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, linux, database

I need to create a database and to transform the files from .batch to .sh, because I'm not using a Windows Server, but a Linux one now. So I need to adapt it to Linux.

The first instructions are:

> It is advisable to pre-allocate 500GB of data storage at the time you create the database, and, set the Recovery Model to “Simple” during the installation.

I see no way of doing this using MySQL... I guess I just have to create the database normally, using CREATE DATABASE command. Is that the only thing I can do in this case?

Is there a way to set a Recovery Model of a database using a mySQL Server? How to do it?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: There is no "Recovery Model" setting in MySQL. Are you looking to replicate Simple Recovery Model in MySQL? I'm not sure this is something you need to worry about if "Simple" is the recommended route in SQL Server.

Comment: So, the instructions of the project are to do it on a SQL Server Database, but I'm going to use a Linux Server and MySQL. This instructions of Recovery Model and data allocation size doesn't apply for my case, right? Since I'm using MySQL to do it.